# how can i add a tableau chart inside a react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i found a public tableau chart and i wan to add it to my react component, the embeded code from chart is :

```
<div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1654073879418' style='position: relative'><noscript><a href='#'><img alt='State Cost Dash ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Bo&#47;Book1_16075518489150&#47;StateCostDash&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' /></a></noscript><object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'><param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='site_root' value='' /><param name='name' value='Book1_16075518489150&#47;StateCostDash' /><param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' /><param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Bo&#47;Book1_16075518489150&#47;StateCostDash&#47;1.png' /> <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' /><param name='display_static_image' value='yes' /><param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' /><param name='display_count' value='yes' /><param name='language' value='en-GB' /></object></div>                <script type='text/javascript'>                    var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1654073879418');                    var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                    if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 800 ) { vizElement.style.width='800px';vizElement.style.height='1247px';} else if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 500 ) { vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height='1237px';} else { vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height='1207px';}                     var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                </script>
```

and i want to ad it inside this :

import React from 'react'

```
const Stats = () => {
  return (
    <div>Stats</div>
  )
}

export default Stats
```